# lftp: bash equivalent of command substitution backticks or $()

Tags: linux, bash, lftp

Is it possible to use bash-like command substitution, like backticks ``` `` ``` or `$()` with lftp?

This is to e.g. cd into a directory given by a command:

```
lftp ..
cd `pwd`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you looking for I guess but you can use `-e` option like this:

```
$ lftp -e "cd $HOME" <SITE>
```

As explained in `man lftp`:

> **-e commands** Execute given commands and don't exit.

So after using `-e` as shown above `lftp` will take you to `$HOME` directory on the remote server.

I don't think it's possible to use all local environment variables inside `lftp` - `man lftp` clearly says that only some variables are honored. 
I think that maybe `ssh` could be a better solution here.

Comment: I guess the short answer is no :) i dont want to script lftp. this is from within lftp.